# Create a stub of 3rd party Java library

Tags: java, stub

My task is to create stubs for a 3rd party Java library that our application will make calls to. My problem is how to define the class of the method "return type" (if that's the correct Java terminology). I don't have access to the full documentation of the 3rd party API, just a list of methods. For now, my stubs just need to return true/false or 1/0, whatever

Here's an example of one method to illustrate. This is what I have been given

```
OobResponse RequestOobRequest(
   String ClientName,
   String SecurityLink,
   short LenofHHU,
   RequestMode RequestMode)
```

I have no idea what OobResponse or RequestMode are supposed to be, but I should still be able to create stubs, right?

So far, this is all I have.

```
public class stubber {

  public class OobResponse {
    public int someVar;
  }
  public class RequestMode {
    public int someVar;
  }

  public OobResponse RequestOobRequest(
    String ClientName,
    String SecurityLink,
    short LenofHHU,
    RequestMode RequestMode)
  {
      OobResponse oobr = new OobResponse();
      return oobr;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Will you replace `OobResponse` and `RequestMode` with the real classes later? I don't see the point in creating a class which just "looks like" a third party library without actually being equivalent.

Comment: Yes, we currently don't have access to the 3rd party API, only its documentations, so we're trying to get as much done in advance. The idea of stubbing it out means we can build our calls to it, and (hopefully) when we do get our hands on it, we can just slot it in instead of the stubs. That's the hope anyway!

Comment: So, what you are basically planning is mocking an API without even knowing the actual used datatypes? I'd save myself the time to create useless code, as you will have to compile all projects using this API once you exchange your fake classes with the real classes and might even have to adjust behavior basing on it.

Comment: @Smutje I hear you, but I've been asked to do this task, and I'm new to Java, so any help you can give would be great.

Comment: yeah, why not just create Java Interfaces for all the classes you know about and then just implement the interfaces later?

Comment: @jordaniac89 I'm a noob, I don't know what you're talking about. Can you show me a simple example of how you would implement the RequestOobRequest method?

Comment: @jordaniac89 did someone delete your answer? I saw it but then it was gone. I thought it seemed like a good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you have is weird, since variable and method names do not hold Java convention of using camelCase. Also, what you seem to be ordered to do would hold minimal later use. However, the way I understand your problem you could do:

- create new package for all classes you will be stubbing. That will be relevant later
- actually stub stuff. That is, for every class in the documentation that is not built into java create the class. I assumed that what you wrote is a method declaration (made most sense to me, though it could also be a constructor or whatever), it needs to be a part of some class, I called it "Unknown" below. Replace that name with actual class name.

For your example you would need:

```
public class RequestMode {

}

public class OobResponse {

}

public class Unknown {

    public OobResponse RequestOobRequest(
            String ClientName,
            String SecurityLink,
            short LenofHHU,
            RequestMode RequestMode){
        return new OobResponse(); // or null, whatever since it is a stub
    }
}
```

Note, that when stubbing you do not create any additional variables (like `someVar` you tried to add), ONLY what API allows you to access (only classes and public methods within would be a good rule of a thumb). You could also use interfaces instead of classes, it would be cleaner, but there are legitimate reasons not to (when you want a code with `new StubbedClass()` to compile for example).

Now, in your actual code you (or someone) will be able to use your stubs like the actual library:

```
public class YourBusinessClass{

     public OobResponse getOobByClientName(String clientName){
         return new Unknown().RequestOobRequest(clientName,...);
     }

}
```

- When you get the actual library you can replace imports from stub package in your actual code that uses it to the actual library package.

That is the only usefull way of using stubs like that I could think of, so I hope that is what you want.

Comment: Ok, this is very similar to what I wrote, which is good. It means I wasn't too far off. The only real difference is that you have put the RequestMode and OobResponse classes outside the Unknown class, where I had them inside. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @JDor In short - yes. You would need to read up on how Java handles classes, inner classes especially. As a rule of a thumb you should not use a class inside a class unless you know you what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility (academically at least) is to use a facade to the actual 3rd party library. You could probably create a class which has the methods that you need and your main code calls this class in place of the the 3rd party library, include all the methods that you need and return 1/0 etc., when the library is available dispatch the calls to the library from the facade.

However, there is a fair bit of caution, if the actual data model of the library is complex you could end up replicating all of them or their equivalent in your code, if it is not (like simple strings etc.) then this approach would work.

With reference to the comment below for en example, i am adding the following:

Let us say we have a class:

```
public class Class0{

 public String method0(String arg0){return "from Method 0";}
 public String method1(String arg0, String arg1){return "from Method 1";}

}//class closing
```

Now let us say we only have the signature for the above class and not the class itself, then we can do the following (for now):

```
public Class0Facade{

 public String method0(String arg0){return "from Method 0";}
 public String method1(String arg0, String arg1){return "from Method 1";}

}//class closing
```

Rest of your code can use the 'class0Facade' class and go ahead.

When the actual Class0 is available, you would change Class0Facade, in the following way:

```
public Class0Facade{

 protected Class0 deligate;

 public Class0Facade(){delegate=new Class0();}
 public String method0(String arg0){return delegate.method0(arg0);}
 public String method1(String arg0, String arg1){return delegate.method(arg0, arg1);}

}//class closing
```

Rest ot four code does not need to change

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm a noob, I don't know what you're talking about. Can you show me a simple example of how you would implement the RequestOobRequest method I defined in my question?

Comment: Just saw your update. Many thanks for the helpful response - it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could go with classes that extend the stubbed classes:

```
public class Stubber extends StubbedClass {
  public OobResponse RequestOobRequest(
    String ClientName,
    String SecurityLink,
    short LenofHHU,
    RequestMode RequestMode) {
      OobResponse oobr = new OobResponse();
      return oobr;
    }
}
```

If you cant create an OobResponse, you could similarly create a *public class OobResponseStub extends OobResponse*

Comment: How should OP extend a class he didn't even have - to invent both and have *two* invented classes afterwards?

Comment: Ah, didn't know that the 3rd party library classes aren't existing yet when I wrote my reply. Of course, you can't use this approach then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't understand though - what is StubbedClass?

Comment: StubbedClass would be the class that you will be using later, if you extend it you could change the behaviour and create a stub that just returns simple objects without logic, Since you don't have this class already, this isn't feasable. If you could manage to get java interfaces instead of only text documentation of the "soon to be available" library you could use these to create simple Stub classes.

Comment: Ah, got you. Thanks. Yeah, it's far from ideal situation, but nothing much I can do about it. I appreciate the reply!